# Sharepoint 2007 File Upload , Page cannot be Displayed

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

Having a bit of strange Sharepoint 2007 issue , especially for a Monday.

Here's the scenario: Users within organisation cannot upload files to ANY doc Lib. 
User is able to click upload, browse, select the file without any problems. As soon as he/she clicks OK, they immediately get a standard IE error : Page cannot be displayed.

The MOSS Server is setup in a DMZ where it is Internet accessible. When accessing it from the Internet (which I'm doing), the uploading works fine. It's only when users who are in the organisation try to upload anything, they get the error. Users within the organistaion also access the site using the Internet IP as no direct route exists between Internal Network and DMZ.

We have a LINUX Firewall involved (Yuck, I know), and clients also have Norton AV.

I suspect some kind of networking issue, or maybe the AV. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. The issue was related to intermittant connectivity loss.
All fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The issue was related to intermittant connectivity loss. All fixed now